# PHP date() produces different results with same timestamp

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I'm trying to debug a php date issue I'm having between 2 servers.  I'm passing a timestamp through the date() function on both servers, but I'm getting 2 different dates.

Server 1:

```
date('d-m-Y', 575766000);
// Outputs 30-03-1988 00:00:00
```

Server 2:

```
date('d-m-Y', 575766000);
// Outputs 31-03-1988 00:00:00
```

I've checked the date on both servers, with the "date" command, and they're both set to:

```
Wed Mar  6 14:42:19 GMT 2013
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the timezone setting on the servers

Comment: try with date_default_timezone_set() for set the idem timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the timezone by logging on to the server and looking at /etc/php.ini depending on how your PHP is configured.

date.timezone="America/New_York"

As of PHP 5.3 you are required to set the timezone. Previously this could be left blank.

Comment: Thanks.  This was it.  Even though I'm on PHP 5.2, one server had it set, and the other one didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct the times of your servers.

PHP takes the time from the server.

Answer (score 0):

if you will try to set the timezone using this:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
```

Then it should work